# Python multiprocessing bug on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, multiprocessing

I need to distribute my python application to some mac users, the application works well on Windows but on Mac OS X something is wrong. Multiprocessing is not working on Mac OS X due http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-ideas/17811/. Is there a workaround to fix the error:

'The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().
Break on **THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY**_YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.'

Thanks a lot for any help :)

Comment: 1. is there some code that can help reproduce the error? 2. You can change the modules content at runtime by setting/replacing attributes.

Comment: at the moment my code is complex, I will try to reproduce the same error but with simplest code.

Comment: I found the reason... in the first process of multiprocessing pool I am using pyqt progress bar that show the global computation status. If I remove the progress bar all works like expected (like on Windows). Is there a simple way to inform the user about global computation status in a multiprocessing application?