# Python Tkinter application causes fork() / exec() error on Mac OS X

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

I'm running a python (2.7) Tkinter GUI application on Mac OS X (10.7 and 10.8). The UI is in a separate process that gets forked off from the main script using multiprocessing. When I run, however, it fails with:

```
'The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec(). Break on THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY_YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.'
```

This works on Windows just fine.

I've found a bug related to it logged with python: http://bugs.python.org/issue8713
But sadly, it looks like the fix was only implemented in 3.x versions but I need to support 2.7 as well.

I know there's a few other SO questions regarding the same error, like this: [Python multiprocessing bug on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057040/)

But I've not been able to figure out what would actually fix the issue in my particular case.

Any thoughts on how to get this to work on Mac?

Code is below. DriverVisualizer() is created (in another script), which initializes the UI on another process.

```
from util import *
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
from Tkinter import *
import threading
import Queue
from time import *

class VisualizerUI:
    def __init__(self, conn, count, pixelSize):
        self._conn = conn
        self._master = Tk()
        self._q = Queue.Queue()

        self._count = count
        self._values = []
        self._leds = []

        self._pixelSize = pixelSize
        self._pixelPad = int(pixelSize / 2)
        self._pixelSpace = 4

        #init colors to all black (off)
        for i in range(self._count):
            self._values.append("#000000")

        self.initUI()

        self._thread = threading.Thread(target=self.commThread).start()

    def mainloop(self):
        self._master.mainloop()
        try:
            self._conn.send({"status" : False})
        except:
            pass

    def updateUI(self):
        try:
            for i in range(self._count):
                    self._canvas.itemconfig(self._leds[i], fill=self._values[i])
        except TclError:
            #Looks like the UI closed!
            pass

    def commThread(self):
        data = None
        error = False

        while True:
            #bit of a hack, but need to check occasionaly for window size change
            if self._width != self._master.winfo_width() or self._height != self._master.winfo_height():
                self._width = self._master.winfo_width()
                self._height = self._master.winfo_height()
                self._master.after_idle(self.layoutPixels)

            try:
                data = self._conn.recv()
            except EOFError:
                error = True
                break

            if data["run"]:
                self._values = data["data"]
                self.updateUI()
                self._conn.send({"status" : True})
            else:
                break
        if not error:
            self._conn.send("Killing UI...")
            self._master.destroy()

    def layoutPixels(self):
        self._canvas.config(width=self._width, height=self._height)
        newRow = True
        x_off = self._pixelPad
        y_off = self._pixelPad
        for i in range(self._count):
            if (x_off + (self._pixelSize * 2) + self._pixelSpace + self._pixelPad) > self._width:
                newRow = True
                y_off = y_off + self._pixelPad + self._pixelSize
            if newRow:
                x_off = self._pixelPad
                newRow = False
            else:
                x_off = x_off + self._pixelSize + self._pixelSpace

            self._canvas.coords(self._leds[i], x_off, y_off, x_off + self._pixelSize, y_off + self._pixelSize)

        y = (y_off + self._pixelSize + self._pixelPad)
        if self._height != y:
            self._master.geometry("{0}x{1}".format(self._width, y))
            self._master.update()

    def __CancelCommand(event=None): 
        pass

    def initUI(self):
        m = self._master
        m.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.__CancelCommand)

        m.title("LED Strip Visualizer")
        m.geometry("1400x50")
        m.update()
        self._width = m.winfo_width()
        self._height = m.winfo_height()
        m.minsize(self._width, self._height)

        self._canvas = Canvas(self._master, background="#000000")
        c = self._canvas
        c.pack(side=TOP)

        for i in range(self._count):
            index = c.create_oval(0,0,self._pixelSize,self._pixelSize, fill=self._values[i])
            self._leds.append(index)

        #m.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)

        self.layoutPixels()

def toHexColor(r,g,b):
    return "#{0:02x}{1:02x}{2:02x}".format(r,g,b)

def startUI(conn, count, pixelSize):
        ui = VisualizerUI(conn, count, pixelSize)
        ui.mainloop()

class DriverVisualizer(object):
    """Main driver for Visualizer UI (for testing)"""

    def __init__(self, leds, pixelSize = 15, showCurrent = False):
        self.leds = leds
        self._showCurrent = showCurrent
        if self._showCurrent:
            self._peakCurrent = 0;
        else:
            self._peakCurrent = None

        self._parent_conn, self._child_conn = Pipe()
        p = Process(target=startUI, args=(self._child_conn, self.leds, pixelSize))

        p.start()
        sleep(0.5) # give the UI some time to spin up before throwing data at it

    def __del__(self):
        self._parent_conn.send({"data" : None, "run" : False})
        print self._parent_conn.recv()

    def calcCurrent(self, data):
        c = 0
        for r, g, b in data:
            c = c + int(((r/255.0) * 20.0) + ((g/255.0) * 20.0) + ((b/255.0) * 20.0))
            if c > self._peakCurrent: 
                self._peakCurrent = c

        return c

    #Push new data to strand
    def update(self, data):
        c = None
        if self._showCurrent:
            c = self.calcCurrent(data)
        self._parent_conn.send({"data" : [toHexColor(*(data[x])) for x in range(self.leds)], "run" : True, "c" : c, "peak" : self._peakCurrent})
        resp = self._parent_conn.recv()
        if not resp["status"]:
            error = True
            parent_conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I run into same problem, check this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19082049/1956309

Which puts you in track to a Tkinter bug here:
http://bugs.python.org/issue5527#msg195480

The solution that did the trick for me (Mac OS 10.8 with Python 2.7) is to rearrange the code so the "import Tkinter" is placed after you have invoked any kind of process.start()

It looks like:

```
import multiprocessing

def cam_loop(the_q):
    while True:
        the_q.put('foo in the queue')

def show_loop(the_q):
    while True:
        from_queue = the_q.get()
        print from_queue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        the_q = multiprocessing.Queue(1)

        cam_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=cam_loop,args=(the_q, ))
        cam_process.start()

        show_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=show_loop,args=(the_q, ))
        show_process.start()

        import Tkinter as tk  # << Here!
        cam_process.join()
        show_loop.join()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        cam_process.terminate()
        show_process.terminate()
```

P.d: Thanks [JW Lim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3155705/jw-lim) for showing me good manners!

Comment: Although this may provide a solution to the question, it would be better if you include the solution from that question into your answer (with proper attribution). Link-only answers tend to become useless if links stop working or, in this particular case, if the other SO question is deleted.